# Define a variable based on the result of the execution of a command in make file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, make, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to use a makefile to bundle a combination of commands that should be run one after the other. Part of the make file looks like the following;

```
.PHONY: dispersion
all: dispersion


-include make.in

dispersion:
    phonopy --qe -d --dim='$(nx) $(ny) $(nz)' -c $(material)_primitive.in 
    $(eval VAR=$(shell grep nat supercell.in))
    echo $(VAR)
```

basically, the first line creates a file called "supercell.in" and the second creates a variable called VAR that will be used in the subsequent lines. The above doesn't assign a value to the variable and I'm guessing this is due to the priority of the execution of lines. I would appreciate knowing a way around this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try using backtick operator to run the command.

```
.PHONY: dispersion
all: dispersion


-include make.in

dispersion:
    phonopy --qe -d --dim='$(nx) $(ny) $(nz)' -c $(material)_primitive.in
    $(eval VAR=`grep nat supercell.in`)
    echo $(VAR)
```

I believe the problem is due to when the `$(shell)` is evaluated by the interpreter.